# Insert Into Select From via jdbc

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to insert into a table by fetching records from another tables, so basically its a "Insert into select from": The question now is can I use the same script which I executed inside Oracle SQL editor to perform this operation?

Here is a sample of what the script looks like:

```
INSERT INTO (name, rollno) 
WITH sample as ( select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by name, rollno order by rollno) , e.id, d.id,
  FROM  employee e INNER JOIN department d ON employee.id=department.employeeId )(select e.id, d.id from sample)
```

Can i use the same script executing via jdbc! This insert statement will go along with Prepared Statement. Do i have to use ? when i am using join clause?

Comment: Yes, if you have a valid SQL statement, you can run that statement from JDBC just as you would via any other API or from a front-end application.  The query you posted does not appear to be valid, however, because you can't reference `e.id` or `d.id` from `sample` since neither the `e` nor the `d` alias is in scope at that point.  So the query you posted would fail no matter where it is run from.

Comment: Did you check the SQL statement is valid? Run it on the database to validate it.